# Add monthly totals from daily date data across multiple years

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2003

I'm working with Excel 2003 and I want to look how certain products are performing so I'm working with monthly revenue and profit and using the following formula:

```
SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(U6)=MONTH(Table5[Date])),Table5[Rev])
```

However, this works well until I add in months from different years. I need to parse by month (which I've done) as well as year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect what you have at the moment to sum for whatever month is represented in U6, regardless of year, so am interpreting the requirement to be the disaggregation of the same month but different year and hence suggest:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(U6)=MONTH(Table5[Date])),Table5[Rev],--(YEAR(U6)=YEAR(Table5[Date])))
```

This should only sum `Rev` entries where the corresponding `Date` entries are the same month *and year* as U6. It might be more convenient to specify the month in one cell (say U6 as at present) and the year independently, say in V6. If so, the last (added) part of the formula should be changed to:

```
--(YEAR(V6)=YEAR(Table5[Date])
```

However better still might be a PivotTable.